# How to target a video file from local to play into a video component

Tags: javascript, angular

Note:

1. i dont want to use any static path.
2. it should be dynamic source, based on user target a file from local, it will able to take path and make that as video component source.
3. i have tried,  but everytime it returns me with some c:/fakepath/file.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, browser won't let you see full file path, it's not save to let js for parse the user's file system.

You need FileReader to use files from local.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" type="file">

<video id="video" src="" controls></video>
```

JS:

```
input.oninput =  (event) => {

  // creating reader
  const reader = new FileReader();

  // after files load finish
  reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    video.src = event.target.result;
  });

  // start load file
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```